# Is this possible? producer batch.size * max.request.size > broker max.message.bytes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Average message size is small, but size is vary.

- Average message size: 1KBytes
- 1MBytes message incomes in arbitrary rate. / So, producer's max.request.size = 1MBytes
- broker's max.message.bytes = 2MBytes

My questions.

1. To avoid producing size error, user have to set batch.size LTE 2?
2. Or producer library decides batch size automatically to avoid error? (even user set large batch.size)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are the definition of the related configs in question

**Producer config**

*batch.size* : producer will attempt to batch records until it reaches batch.size before it is sent to kafka ( assuming batch.size is configured to take precedence over linger.ms ) .Default - 16384 bytes

*max.request.size* : The maximum size of a request in bytes. This setting will limit the number of record batches the producer will send in a single request to avoid sending huge requests. This is also effectively a cap on the maximum record batch size. Default - 1048576 bytes

**Broker config**

*message.max.bytes* : The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka. Default - 1000012 bytes

*replica.fetch.max.bytes* : This will allow for the replicas in the brokers to send messages within the cluster and make sure the messages are replicated correctly.

**To answer your questions**

1. To avoid producer send errors , you don't need to set batch size 2MB as this will delay the transmission of your low size messages . You can keep the batch.size according to the avg message size and depending on how much you want to batch
2. If you don't specify batch size , it would take the default value which is 
   16384 bytes

So basically you will have to configure producer 'max.request.size'>=2MB and broker 'message.max.bytes' and 'replica.fetch.max.bytes' >=2MB.

Comment: Producer will send messages immediately when sender thread is free. Producer is not waiting to fill batch.size completely - if you have batch.size set to default 16384b and producer have 5b in batch, those 5 bytes will be send immedietally when sender thread is free. If you'd like to wait some time and buffer more data you need to set linger.ms higer than zero.

Answer (score 8):

This query arises because there are various settings available around batching. Let me attempt to make them clear:

**Kafka Setting: `message.max.bytes` and `fetch.max.bytes`**

The Kafka broker limits the maximum size (total size of messages in a batch, if messages are published in batches) of a message that can be produced, configured by the cluster-wide property `message.max.bytes` (defaults to 1 MB). A producer that tries to send a message larger than this will receive an error back from the broker, and the message will not be accepted. As with all byte sizes specified on the broker, this configuration deals with compressed message size, which means that producers can send messages that are much larger than this value uncompressed, provided they compress it under the configured `message.max.bytes` size.

Note: This setting can be overridden by a specific topic (but with name `max.message.bytes`).

The maximum message size, `message.max.bytes`, configured on the Kafka broker must be coordinated with the cluster-wide property `fetch.max.bytes` (defaults to 1 MB) on consumer clients. It configures the maximum number of bytes of messages to attempt to fetch for a request. If this value is smaller than `message.max.bytes`, then consumers that encounter larger messages will fail to fetch those messages, resulting in a situation where the consumer gets stuck and cannot proceed.

The configuration setting `replica.fetch.max.bytes` (defaults to 1MB) determines the rough amount of memory you will need for each partition on a broker.

**Producer Setting: `max.request.size`**

This setting controls the size of a produce request sent by the producer. It caps both the size of the largest message that can be sent and the number of messages that the producer can send in one request. For example, with a default maximum request size of 1 MB, the largest message you can send is 1MB or the producer can batch 1000 messages of size 1k each into one request.

In addition, the broker has its own limit on the size of the largest message it will accept `message.max.bytes`). It is usually a good idea to have these configurations match, so the producer will not attempt to send messages of a size that will be rejected by the broker.

Note that `message.max.bytes` (broker level) and `max.requrest.size` (producer level) **puts a cap on the maximum size of request in a batch**, but `batch.size` (which should be lower than previous two) and `linger.ms` are the settings which actually **govern the size of the batch**.

**Producer Setting: `batch.size` and `linger.ms`**

When multiple records are sent to the same partition, the producer will batch them together. The parameter `batch.size` controls the maximum amount of memory in bytes (not the number of messages!) that will be used for each batch. If a batch has become full, all the message in the batch has to be sent. This helps in throughput on both the client and the server.

A small batch size will make batching less common and may reduce throughput. A very large size may use memory a bit more wastefully as we will always allocate a buffer of the specified batch size in anticipation of additional messages.

The `linger.ms` (defaults to 0) setting controls the amount of time to wait for additional messages before sending the current batch.

By default, the producer will send messages as soon as there is a sender thread available to send them, even if there's just one message in the batch (note that `batch.size` only specifies the maximum limit on the size of a batch). By setting linger.ms higher than 0, we instruct the producer to wait a few milliseconds to add additional messages to the batch before sending it to the brokers, even if a sender thread is available. This increases latency but also increases throughput (because we send more messages at once, there is less overhead per message).

Comment: Long answer:-) But very helpful. Thanks.